# Query on Nested Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, subdocument

How can i find only one document which matches my filter

machine_name: ABT6 and process days : 33

I need only one doc to be returned.

[
{
    "_id": "5a7ca2227c42ac67682731d5",
    "machine_name": "ABT6",
    "process": [
        {
            "_id": "5a2ca22b7c42ad67682731d5",
            "days": 33,
            "activity":"Go to elevator 1"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5a2ca72b0a1aa173aaae07da",
            "days": true,
            "activity":"Go to elevator 4"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5a2cabf85a41077a2f87d4e3",
            "days": false,
            "activity":"Go to elevator 4"
        }
    ]
}
]

Comment: $elemMatch does not rerturn a single nested document, instead it returns all the sub docs

Answer (score 0):

You need to add projection : [$ (projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_)

```
db.collectionName.find({ machine_name : "ABT6","process.days" : 33},{"process.$" : 1,machine_name: 1}).pretty()
```

also with  $elemMatch :

```
db.collectionName.find({ machine_name : "ABT6","process": { $elemMatch : { days: 33 }}},{"process.$" : 1,machine_name: 1}).pretty()
```

Comment: This returns empty array even if the content matches. @the_mahasagar